# If 01Knapsack is exponential, why is a loop from 1 to n linear?

Tags: algorithm, knapsack-problem, np, np-complete

I've read a lot of question here on StackOverflow about this, and they all make a good point: the complexity of the DP approach to the Knapsack problem is O(nW) which is exponnetial in the number of bits in W. That is, if I add one more bit to W, I need twice as many loops.

The algorithm is pretty much:

```
For i = 0 to n
   For w = 0 to W
      //Stuff
```

But if I look at an algorithm like summing from 1 to n (= n(n+1)/2) I will only have a for loop. And if I increment the number of bits needed to represent n by 1, well, I need to do twice as many loops. So is this exponential as well?

My only possible understanding is that, in this case the size of the input is "n", whereas in the Knapsack the size of the input is the number of bits needed to represent W. But,... why? Why are these two sizes different? The loops look the same.

Thanks.

Comment: Yes, the algorithm you gave for summing from 1 to n takes exponential time in the size of its input (which is O(log(n)) bits), just like the knapsack DP algorithm.  Both are usually called "pseudopolynomial" algorithms, because although they take time exponential in the *size* of the input, they still only take time polynomial in the *value* of the input.

Comment: Good question, BTW.  Another example is: To factor a given number k, you can just run a loop variable i from 1 up to k, attempting to divide k by i at each iteration.  Integer division is polynomial-time, so this seems to suggest that factoring an integer is poly-time too...  But it's not, because the *size* of the input k is not k -- it's just O(log k) bits.

Comment: Thanks I think I understand. I have to look at the size of the input.
I am still pretty sure I've hear people say that the sum algorithm would be linear, and it does not shock me... Is there a thing like "complexity in value" and "complexity in size"? Or is it just people getting it wrong? Thanks

Comment: It's something people often get confused about.  Part of the problem is that there's no completely clear, formal way of *encoding* the input to a problem...  Just (usually) a "standard" encoding.  E.g. if you were to declare that the weight W must be specified *in unary* (i.e. as a sequence of 1-bits), then it would take O(W) bits to encode the value W, so the running time O(nW) would indeed be polynomial in the input *size* n+W.  ;-)